# How to solve: "Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(X[[2L]], ...) : 'origin' must be supplied"

Tags: r, loops, time

we have created the following loop to plot the different parts of the data (with the package "latticeExtra").

```
library("latticeExtra")
All_dates<-unique(fad$Meet_date)
for (i in 1:11) { Date.i <- All_dates[i]
  layoutno <- unique(fad[fad$Meet_date == Date.i,28] )
  Data.i <- fad[fad$Meet_date == Date.i, ]
  Data.i$newtime <- as.POSIXct(Data.i$DateTime)
  prop <- with(Data.i,tapply(newtime,klasse, max))-with(Data.i,tapply(newtime,klasse, min))
png(paste(Date.i, ".png", sep = ""), height = 20, width = 30, units = "cm", res = 400)
dog <- xyplot(Ratio ~ Meet_times |as.factor(klasse), data = Data.i, main = paste(Date.i), 
layout = c(layoutno,1), scales = list(x = list(relation = "free",format  = "%H:%M")), 
xlab = "Time of measurement", ylab = "Ratio CH4/CO2")
print(resizePanels(dog,w = prop))
dev.off() }
```

However, we get this: Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(X[[2L]], ...) : 'origin' must be supplied.. 
I am a big noob with R, so I have no idea where this problem could lie.. My collegue also seems to be lost.. I know it is a big code, but I kinda hoped someone sees the problem rigthaway.. I tried several searches on this website and on Google, but this did not get me anything useful.

Please, help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The error tells you exactly where the problem lies, and `help("as.POSIXct.numeric")` has examples of how to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, so I filled in a wrong column number as a reference point, that's what went wrong. We forgot that we added a column earlier in the script, so instead of using the 28th column, it needed to use the 29th.. The difference between these columns was that one is numeric and the other is POSIXlt.. Probably, that's why I got that error.. Kind of stupid you could say. Anyways, thanks to everyone who bothered to take the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's easy to get this problem to go away, but you need to be careful to get the date conversions right.  The problem is that you are passing a number to `as.POSIXct` and not a `Date` object, and when you pass an integer, you need to give an origin date, so that it can compute the offset.  For example:

```
> date<-as.Date("2013-10-18")
> as.POSIXct(date)
[1] "2013-10-17 20:00:00 EDT"
> date0<-unclass(date)
> date0
[1] 15996
> as.POSIXct(date0)
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(date0) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

The real question is, how are you representing your dates in `fad$Meet_date` (and also why do you want to convert them to POSIXct).  The correct origin and conversion will depend on what `fad$Meet_date` represents.