# Error: origin must be supplied

Tags: r, datetime

I have the following code to clean a dataset.

```
data1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = year(DATE), 
         MONTH = month(DATE), 
         DAY=day(DATE), 
         HOUR=hour(TIME), 
         MINUTE = minute(TIME), 
         RETURN= ((PRICE-lag(PRICE))/lag(PRICE))
  ) %>% 
  filter(HOUR >= 9, (HOUR <= 16 & MINUTE <=61)) %>%
  group_by(MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, MONTH, YEAR) %>% 
  summarize(AV.PRICE = mean(PRICE, na.rm=TRUE), 
            SUM.SIZE=sum(SIZE, na.rm=TRUE),
            RV=sum(RET^2)) %>%
  arrange(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE) %>%
  mutate(DATETIME = as.POSIXct(
    paste(YEAR,"/",MONTH,"/", DAY, " ", HOUR,":", MINUTE,":00",sep=""), 
    format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", origin = "1970-01-01")
  )
```

However, it sometimes gives me the error message: `Error: 'origin' must be supplied`

What is strange is that the error does not appear on the first time I run this code in the session, but appears on subsequent runs. If I restart the session, the problem disappears for once and returns in later runs. Hence I have to always restart to get it to work.

I checked the question: [How to solve: "Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(X[[2L]], ...) : 'origin' must be supplied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449307/how-to-solve-error-in-as-posixct-numericx2l-origin-must-be-supp) which suggested that it might be because it is converting from integer to time. However a `glimpse` of the data shows that that the DATE is a `<date>` class and not an integer.

To be safe: I followed the suggestion of the error and added an origin = "1970-01-01" argument to all of the functions dealing with dates:

```
data1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = year(DATE, origin = "1970-01-01"),
         MONTH = month(DATE, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
         DAY=day(DATE, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
         HOUR=hour(TIME, origin = "1970-01-01"),
         MINUTE = minute(TIME, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
         RET= ((PRICE-lag(PRICE))/lag(PRICE))
  ) %>% 
  filter(HOUR >= 9, (HOUR <= 16 & MINUTE <=61)) %>%
  group_by(MINUTE,HOUR,DAY,MONTH,YEAR) %>% 
  summarize(AV.PRICE = mean(PRICE, na.rm=TRUE), 
            SUM.SIZE=sum(SIZE, na.rm=TRUE),
            RV=sum(RET^2)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE) %>% 
  mutate(DATETIME = as.POSIXct(
    paste(YEAR,"/",MONTH,"/", DAY, " ", HOUR,":", MINUTE,":00",sep=""), 
    format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", origin = "1970-01-01")
  )
```

and it returns `Error: unused argument (origin = "1970-01-01")`

If it helps, here is a glimpse of my dataset:

```
Observations: 146,016,609
Variables: 4
$ DATE  <date> 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, 2008-01-02, ...
$ TIME  <S4: Period> 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S, 9H 0M 4S...
$ PRICE <dbl> 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.86, 146.8...
$ SIZE  <int> 1000, 1000, 1000, 500, 2400, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2500, 1000, 1000, 400, 1000, 1000, 100...
```

I'm looking for an answer using base package functions or at most lubridate/dplyr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or use `anydate()` from the anytime package:

```
R> anydate(20170314L)  # integer
[1] "2017-03-14"
R> anydate(20170314)   # numeric
[1] "2017-03-14"
R> anydate("20170314") # character 
[1] "2017-03-14"
R> anydate(as.factor("20170314")) 
[1] "2017-03-14"
R>
```

and much more, including guessing most (sane) date (and datetime for `anytime()`) formats --- and no requirement for (mostly redundant) origins.

*Edit:* Given *your* data, you are making it way to complicated.  Try this:

Minimal data.frame object

```
R> df <- data.frame(DATE=rep(as.Date("2008-01-02"),4), TIME=rep(period(c(9,0,4), c("hour", "minute", "second")), 4))
R> df
        DATE     TIME
1 2008-01-02 9H 0M 4S
2 2008-01-02 9H 0M 4S
3 2008-01-02 9H 0M 4S
4 2008-01-02 9H 0M 4S
R>
```

Just *add* Date and Time

```
R> df$DATE + df$TIME
[1] "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC"
R> class(df$DATE + df$TIME)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
R> as.POSIXct(df$DATE + df$TIME)
[1] "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC" "2008-01-02 09:00:04 UTC"
R>
```

And there is your answer.

Comment: Hey I was trying out your package, I don't get the origin errors anymore, but I get NAs for the DATETIME. Please see revised question for code. I'm not familiar with your package, so sorry if I'm not seeing something basic.

Comment: You get NA from `anytime()` or `anydate()` when your input is unparseable by all available formats.  You can add a custom format, see the package help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error `Error: 'origin' must be supplied`  while using `lubridate` package - `hms()` function . The culprit was that the code was referring to function `hms()` from `hms` package . So when I referenced it to `lubridate::hms()`, the error vanished.

```
air_reserve <- 
  air_reserve %>% 
  mutate( Reserve.time = lubridate::hms(Reserve.time)
          , Visit.time = lubridate::hms(Visit.time)
          , Hours = lubridate::hour(Visit.time) )
```